# Representing a phrase as a block of code

Tags: javascript, sql, .net

How can I represent the concept “I have 99 issues but a bug ain’t one” using some fancy code?

Background

I picked the lead dev for Secret Santa. I’d like to get him a tshirt with the above on it expressed as a block of code / fuction / query string. 
We were all in a meeting one day discussing Jira issues and he said “I have 99 issues” and I shouted out “but a bug ain’t one” and everyone had a good laugh. 
So I’d like to put that on a tshirt for him as it think it would be a fun present.
He is a really awesome guy, super smart, always has time to explain something to us non tech folk, a real heat of gold. 
Can you help me?

If it could have something to do with .net/SQL/Bash that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very goofy question but I'll shoot xD.

Javascript Classical

```
class Me{
  issues: 99,
  bug: 0,
}
```

JavaScript Functional

```
function status() {
  if (I.problems === 99 && I.bugs !== 1) {
    console.log('hit it');
  }
}
```

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM I
WHERE issues=99 AND bugs<>1;
```